# Unity window keyboard shortcuts in Xubuntu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xubuntu, window-manager

One of the only things I like about Unity is its window positioning keyboard shortcuts (e.g. Super+NUMPAD9 to position the window at the top right).

Is there anything similar for Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

[compiz](http://wiki.compiz.org/) fusion has this and can be installed on xubuntu. The plugin is called [grid](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Grid) and is also enabled with unity. There is enough information on the web how to install compiz on xubuntu.